# JAGS: Different results when assigning priors to regression coefficients with a for loop than one by one directly

Tags: r, bayesian, jags

I want to loop through my coefficients to assign them priors, as demonstrated below:

```
data(state)

df <- data.frame(state.x77,state.area,state.center,row.names = state.name)


pacman::p_load(runjags, rjags)


dat.mr3 <- with(df, list(x = data.matrix(df[,c("Murder","Illiteracy")]), Life.Exp = Life.Exp, n = nrow(df), K = 2))


mr3_string <- "model{
# sampling model
for(i in 1 : n) {  
  Life.Exp[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i],tau) 
  mu[i] <- beta0 + inprod(beta[],x[i,])
}

beta0 ~ dnorm(0,0.1)

for (j in 1:2) {
    beta[j] ~ dnorm(0,0.1)
}



tau ~ dgamma(0.01,0.01)
}"


inits.mr3 <- function(seed = sample(1:1e4,1)) { 
  set.seed(seed) 
  list(beta0 = rnorm(1), beta = rnorm(2), tau = 1,.RNG.name="base::Super-Duper", .RNG.seed=seed)
}

inits.list.mr3 = lapply(1:3, inits.mr3)

mr3.fit <- run.jags(model = mr3_string, monitor=c("beta0","beta","tau"), data=dat.mr3, n.chains=3, method="rjags", inits=inits.list.mr3, burnin=5e4, sample=10e4, plots = TRUE)


summary(mr3.fit)

              Lower95      Median      Upper95        Mean          SD
beta0    1.9163733155 8.334620372 15.048182351 8.351384333 3.341635348
beta[1]  4.7072838604 6.139846435  7.613527073 6.143863238 0.747693076
beta[2] -2.8218949955 2.966702254  8.863912452 2.970514560 2.989409184
tau      0.0007136679 0.001202235  0.001798534 0.001226712 0.000282493
        Mode        MCerr MC%ofSD SSeff         AC.10     psrf
beta0     NA 1.929294e-02     0.6 30000 -0.0008948207 1.000185
beta[1]   NA 4.343455e-03     0.6 29633  0.0020678594 1.000070
beta[2]   NA 1.702743e-02     0.6 30823  0.0011044000 1.000172
tau       NA 1.630974e-06     0.6 30000  0.0012946102 1.000025
```

Comparing the median estimates to the least squares estimates, I notice a discrepancy in the coefficient estimates:

```
> summary(lm(Life.Exp~Murder+Illiteracy,df))

Call:
lm(formula = Life.Exp ~ Murder + Illiteracy, data = df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.80433 -0.47593  0.06604  0.42339  2.53621 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 73.02758    0.28568 255.623  < 2e-16 ***
Murder      -0.26395    0.04641  -5.688 7.96e-07 ***
Illiteracy  -0.17225    0.28106  -0.613    0.543    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.8529 on 47 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6128,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5963 
F-statistic: 37.19 on 2 and 47 DF,  p-value: 2.071e-10
```

So, I try assigning the priors directly instead of with the forloop, and my estimates completely change to be much closer to the least squares estimates:

```
mr3_string <- "model{
# sampling model
for(i in 1 : n) {  
  Life.Exp[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i],tau) 
  mu[i] <- beta0 + inprod(beta[],x[i,])
}

beta0 ~ dnorm(0,0.1)
beta[1] ~ dnorm(0,0.1)
beta[2] ~ dnorm(0,0.1)

tau ~ dgamma(0.01,0.01)
}"


inits.mr3 <- function(seed = sample(1:1e4,1)) { 
  set.seed(seed) 
  list(beta0 = rnorm(1), beta = rnorm(2), tau = 1,.RNG.name="base::Super-Duper", .RNG.seed=seed)
}

inits.list.mr3 = lapply(1:3, inits.mr3)

mr3.fit <- run.jags(model = mr3_string, monitor=c("beta0","beta","tau"), data=dat.mr3, n.chains=3, method="rjags", inits=inits.list.mr3, burnin=5e4, sample=10e4, plots = TRUE)


           Lower95      Median    Upper95        Mean         SD Mode
beta0   71.6103013 72.34962822 72.9947464 72.32675443 0.35679417   NA
beta[1] -0.3220211 -0.22054706 -0.1188791 -0.21952914 0.05181635   NA
beta[2] -0.5522247  0.03345511  0.6569161  0.03960718 0.30855559   NA
tau      0.6968491  1.20447521  1.7879190  1.22400378 0.28380675   NA
               MCerr MC%ofSD SSeff      AC.10      psrf
beta0   0.0023820291     0.7 22436 0.18017743 0.9999976
beta[1] 0.0003987767     0.8 16884 0.31234820 1.0001722
beta[2] 0.0022923971     0.7 18117 0.28553592 1.0002652
tau     0.0017287382     0.6 26952 0.05888996 0.9999560
```

Why is this happening? It is not overly tedious to assign them directly when there are not many variables, however, I would like to use a large number of predictors, which would make this very tedious. I cannot see anything in the code that would be causing these results to differ

Trace plots:

With for loop:
[image: With for loop]

Direct assignment:
[image: Direct assignment]

Comment: I was just wondering if the mixing of the schemes is the same? In my experience, the mixing in JAGS can be sensitive to the way you have specified the model, even when the different specifications are mathematically identical. Attaching some trace plots from the MCMC chains would address this

Comment: @jcken I have added the trace plots

Answer (score 0):

Both definitions of the model seem to be the same, at least I do not see anything strange as well. JAGS is a declarative language, and the for loop assignment is perfectly valid from the syntax point of view, so they should not differ. So I agree, it's strange.

JAGS is not actively maintained, the last update is from 2017 if I see correctly. Additionally, it is a one-man project to a great degree. Both are red flags for software<sup>*</sup>. I'd encourage you to switch to something more modern and actively maintained, e.g. [Stan](https://mc-stan.org/).

<sup>* - Although JAGS was pretty popular a few years ago and there is a lot of one-man projects in open source, including things I maintain myself.</sup>